# Autofocus blank space in dropbox without creating an empty option?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a `select` that has dynamically created `option` option[0] always ends up being autofocused making my `onchange` not work if I want to choose the first option. 
The index of the options matter so creating a `" "` option won't work.
Any ideas?

---

edit: The user creates an object. When the user saves the object, it creates a new option in the select tag. The user selects something from the select tag to go back to that object.

The autofocus is always on `option[0]` until they selected something else even if they created a new object/option so if they wanted to pick the first thing, but was on the second or third the user would have to click on another option first then click on the one they want.
What I want is that it doesn't focus on any of the options so that they could click on option[0] from the beginning regardless of whether they've selected anything from the dropdown.

Comment: You need to add more context about what you expect the user to be doing. Then another set of events can be used (perhaps blur or click). Are they going to repick the already selected option? Tab through it? Something else?

Comment: One other question - why in the world would the index of the option matter?

Comment: the index corresponds to the index in an array of objects.

Comment: I made them parallel arrays because the objects itself don't have a name.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off tracking the chosen option by value, name or the html5 data attribute. Tracking by index is going to be prone to breakage. These other options will allow you to have a blank or Please Choose option in your dropdown list and a more robust implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a lot of work to workaround this issue, instead of changing one of your requirements.  You say that the index corresponds to an index into an array of objects.  Why can't you have the first option blank or "Select...", and then simply subtract one for your lookup into the array?

Or, have the values correspond to the array index, or use custom data attributes to store the array indexes?  Seems like any of these would be easier than trying to force a consistent behavior for an unsupported functionality across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A Select box always has one of its options selected (unless it doesn't have any options). You might need to use a different event (onclick, perhaps) and test the value to see if it has changed.

Comment: I believe `onclick` for this purpose doesnt work on some browsers.

Comment: Yes I think you are correct... I think in the past I've used onchange, onkeyup, and onblur in order to cover them all (overkill, but it was my only workaround for this same issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default empty selected option with:

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value=""></option>
```

The select is empty by default, with the void option not selectable in the options list.